# Extracting frames every second of all videos in folder

Tags: python, loops, opencv, ffmpeg, frames

I am trying to extract a frame every second of a video, while having multiple videos in a folder. I got it working for 1 video like this, but I think I am messing up my loop for all videos. Below is the code for 1 video that works.

```
import cv2
pathOut = r"C:/Users/Me/Out/"
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:\Me\Desktop\test.mp4');
count = 0
success = True
while success:
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print('read a new frame:',success)
    if count%30 == 0 :
         cv2.imwrite(pathOut + 'frame%d.jpg'%count,image)
    count+=1
```

With the loop for all videos I made it up like this.

```
import os
import cv2
pathOut = r"C:/Users/Me/Out/"
count = 0
success = True
counter = 1
listing = os.listdir(r'C:/Users/Me/videos/train')
for vid in listing:
    vid = r"C:/Users/Me/videos/train/"+vid
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
    count = 0
    counter += 1
    while success:
        success,image = cap.read()
        print('read a new frame:',success)
        if count%30 == 0 :
             cv2.imwrite(pathOut + 'frame%d.jpg'%count,image)
        count+=1
```

My vid loop does not seems to work because it is only taking one video. Then it states false, probably because there are no frames left, but I do not know how to push it forward to the next video. I think I need to do some minor adjustment, does anybody have any idea what exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a minor logical mistake: Once success has been set to false by the first video, it will never be set to true again and all subsequent while loops for all videos will be skipped. Try changing your program to:

```
import os
import cv2
pathOut = r"C:/Users/Me/Out/"
count = 0
counter = 1
listing = os.listdir(r'C:/Users/Me/videos/train')
for vid in listing:
    vid = r"C:/Users/Me/videos/train/"+vid
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
    count = 0
    counter += 1
    success = True
    while success:
        success,image = cap.read()
        print('read a new frame:',success)
        if count%30 == 0 :
             cv2.imwrite(pathOut + 'frame%d.jpg'%count,image)
        count+=1
```

Comment: Thanks I am gonna try this in a few hours ,but it makes sense what you are saying! You will here back from me!

Comment: It works! The only problem is that it keeps overwriting itself, because  for instance frame1.jpg is created multiple times. I was thinking of adding not just count but also the counter. Any clue of how to dot his?

Comment: cv2.imwrite(pathOut + 'frame%d%d.jpg'%count%counter ,image). I tried this but I am probably wrong doing it this way

Comment: Solved it: cv2.imwrite(pathOut + 'video%d'%counter + 'frame%d.jpg'%count ,image)

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are only video type files and not any other type in the dir specified, this should work (Note: there is no regex to select files with specific extension.)

Additional note: Don't have enough reputation to add a comment, hence adding it as answer.

What is the need for `vid = r"C:/Users/Me/videos/train/"+vid` ?
Did you mean to append filename and directory name? If yes, try `os.path.join`

Comment: Thanks, I'll adjust it to path.join!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import cv2

# Define the path to the input videos folder and the output folder for frames
input_folder = r"F:\office_work\Dataset_prediction\videos"  # Replace with the path to your input videos folder
output_folder = r"F:\office_work\Dataset_prediction\output"  # Replace with the path to your output frames folder

# Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

# List all the files in the input folder
videos = [f for f in os.listdir(input_folder) if f.endswith(".mp4")]

# Loop through each video file
for video_file in videos:
    # Construct the full path to the video file
    video_path = os.path.join(input_folder, video_file)
    
    # Open the video file
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    # Check if the video was successfully opened
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Could not open video: {video_file}")
        continue
    
    # Initialize counters and flags
    frame_count = 0
    success = True

    # Loop through frames
    while success:
        # Read a frame from the video
        success, frame = cap.read()
        
        # Check if the read was successful
        if success:
            # Calculate the time (in seconds) of the current frame
            time_in_seconds = frame_count // cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

            # Save the frame if it's at 1-second intervals
            if frame_count % int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)) == 0:
                frame_filename = f"{video_file}_frame_{time_in_seconds}s.jpg"
                frame_path = os.path.join(output_folder, frame_filename)
                cv2.imwrite(frame_path, frame)

            # Increment the frame count
            frame_count += 1

    # Release the video capture object
    cap.release()

# Close all OpenCV windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For me this code work as well also link to github in case its has some update in code: https://github.com/wamiqraza/pre-process-script